# Serialize a map of lambda functions

Tags: java, serialization, lambda

I have `Type2 extends Type1`.

And I have a map of functions:

```
private final Map<String, Consumer<Type1>> functionMap;
{
        functionMap = new HashMap<>();    
        functionMap.put("test", (Type1 t) -> evalSessionSetupReq((Type2) t));
}
```

That works fine. But when I try to serialize that map, I get a `NotSerializableException` exception.

I tried to use:

```
functionMap.put("test", (Serializable)(Type1 t) -> evalSessionSetupReq((Type2) t));
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I serialize such a map of lambda functions?

Comment: You can't really serialize a map of "code" (or callbacks), but you can serialize data and with that data find the good code to call maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can cast the lambda to the intersection of the functional interface and `Serializable` to make it serializable. Try this:

```
functionMap.put("test", 
      (Consumer<Type1> & Serializable)((Type1 t) -> evalSessionSetupReq((Type2) t)));
```